# How to suppress BluetoothLeScanner logs?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to get rid of those annoying logs

```
11-17 09:56:46.102 24862-29194/my.app D/BluetoothLeScanner: onScanResult() - ScanResult{mDevice=68:F7:F1:66:7F:58, mScanRecord=ScanRecord [mAdvertiseFlags=6, mServiceUuids=null, mManufacturerSpecificData={76=[12, 14, 0, -33, 112, -93, -94, 51, 81, -23, 24, 31, -110, 121, 116, -12]}, mServiceData={}, mTxPowerLevel=-2147483648, mDeviceName=null], mRssi=-59, mTimestampNanos=7365019329223}
```

Looking inside `BluetoothLeScanner` reveals that this behaviour is controlled via DBG variable.

```
    /**
     * Callback reporting an LE scan result.
     *
     * @hide
     */
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(final ScanResult scanResult) {
        if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "onScanResult() - " + scanResult.toString());

        // Check null in case the scan has been stopped
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mClientIf <= 0) return;
        }
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mScanCallback.onScanResult(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES, scanResult);
            }
        });

    }
```

So I've tried to use reflection to change this parameter, but without luck.

```
try {
        Field dbg = BluetoothLeScanner.class.getDeclaredField("DBG");
        dbg.setAccessible(true);
        System.out.println("dbg = " + dbg.getBoolean(null));
        dbg.setBoolean(null, false);

        Field vdbg = BluetoothLeScanner.class.getDeclaredField("VDBG");
        vdbg.setAccessible(true);
        System.out.println("vdbg = " + vdbg.getBoolean(null));
        vdbg.setBoolean(null, false);

    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But it's look that this have no effect at all. Event debugger is not able to hit breakpoint in `onScanResult` method. Does anyone have some clues why this could not work? My own suspicion is that maybe this code is executed in different classLoader or process than main application.

Comment: you can use a regex filter to hide them from the logcat

Comment: @TimCastelijns using regexes to whitelist/blacklist logcat is a devs hell

Comment: @Odys do give a better solution if you have one